# Push Objects with Dynamically Allocated Names into Array - AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is this possible? For example, if I had 100 items named item1.....item100, could I add them all to an array using a loop? Something along these lines....but this doesn't work obviously:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
     myArray.push("label" + 1);
}
```

Luckily I only have 10 items, so I can do it manually, but I'm just curious for future reference...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [array access operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#array_access) will let you reference properties and objects by name like that, so if you have:

```
myArray.push(label1);
```

You can use this instead:

```
myArray.push(this["label" + 1]);
```

Comment: In a for loop as you've done you would of course use the iterator. I'm just illustrating equivalent references though.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on on you mean by "items".

If they are properties of the current class use:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    myArray.push(this["label" + i]);
}
```

Comment: Also, correct! Thanks! I'll give you a vote up as soon as I get enough rep :D Edit: Done!

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the link to the object instance to push it into the array, for example if the names of your text fields are `label1`, `label2`, etc. you can use the following code:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
     myArray.push(labelsContainer.getChildByName("label" + i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this even if the names of the objects do not follow any particular pattern but they have to be inside a 'container' (you will add all objects from the container to the array):

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < containerName.numChildren; i++)
{
    myArray.push(containerName.getChildAt(i);
}
```